# Dealing with consecutive rows calculations

Tags: sql, oracle, plsql, oracle11g

Assume the following situation:

- Week 1:

  - *0* previous cases
  - *10* new cases
  - *3* resolved cases
- Week 2:

  - *7* previous cases
  - *13* new cases
  - *15* resolved cases
- Week 3:

  - *5* previous cases
  - *6* new cases
  - *7* resolved cases

This information is stored in a resumed table of the sort:

```
RESUME_TABLE:
WEEK    | TOTAL_NEW |   TOTAL_SOLVED
1       |   10      |   3
2       |   13      |   15
3       |   6       |   7
```

I am having a hard time build a query to obtain the following result:

```
REPORT_TABLE:
WEEK    |   PREV_TOTAL  |   NEW_CASES   |   SOLVED_CASES    |   NEW_TOTAL
1       |   0           |   10          |   3               |   7
2       |   7           |   13          |   15              |   5
3       |   5           |   6           |   7               |   4
```

The idea seems pretty trivial, `NEW_TOTAL = PREV_TOTAL + NEW_CASES - SOLVED_CASES`, though I have been struggling with the idea of carrying the `PREV_TOTAL` to the next row in order to go on.

I am trying to do it using a view over the `RESUME` table (Oracle 11g).

Can someone help me with some example code?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Pretty simple and neat with analytic functions:

```
12:57:06 HR@vm_xe> l                                                                    
  1  select week                                                                        
  2         ,lag(total_cases_by_now - total_solved_by_now) over (order by week) prev_total
  3         ,total_new new_cases                                                        
  4         ,total_solved solved_cases                                                  
  5         ,total_cases_by_now - total_solved_by_now new_total                         
  6    from (                                                                           
  7    select week                                                                      
  8           ,total_new                                                                
  9           ,total_solved                                                             
 10           ,sum(total_new) over(order by week asc) as total_cases_by_now             
 11           ,sum(total_solved) over (order by week asc) as total_solved_by_now        
 12      from resume_table                                                              
 13* )                                                                                  
12:57:07 HR@vm_xe> /                                                                    

      WEEK   PREV_TOTAL  NEW_CASES SOLVED_CASES  NEW_TOTAL                                
---------- ------------ ---------- ------------ ----------                                
         1                      10            3          7                                
         2            7         13           15          5                                
         3            5          6            7          4                                

3 rows selected.                                                                        

Elapsed: 00:00:00.01
```

Comment: pretty cool, I was trying to reach something like that though I never took the time to learn analytical well enough :(

Comment: I find this solution very elegant, but I am having problems to add more details to is. For example, I also wanted to separate the cases by type, so I tried adding on `,sum(total_solved) over (partition by case_type, week order by week asc)` but didn't work (yes I have the the "case_type" columns on the resume table and did the same to the `total_cases_by_now` field and added it to the many `select` statements). Is this the right way to do it?

Comment: remove `week` from `partition by` for starters. this collapses analytic window to just one week instead of all weeks of current type. and you need to partition lag function either, btw

Comment: @filippo can you update your initial post with your current partitioning test case so I could look?

Comment: Hi, one last update, I managed to reproduce the exact problem. Mind taking a look into this fiddle: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/aaedc/1

Comment: @filippo had no time to make it neat and elegant right now, but this is probably what you want http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/aaedc/30

Comment: @beherenow Hey, thanks for all the help man. That one was pretty close, though it might be even simpler than that. You see, I was only using the outmost `group by` to check the totals. What I was interested was breaking down the counts by the other dimensions (that's why I started trying with the partitions). Here is a more specific example: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/aaedc/57 you can seen how the "new total" carries all the `alm_type`s. TIPs? Thanks again!

Answer (score 2):

You can solve this with [MODEL](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/server.112/e25554/sqlmodel.htm#g1042989) clause:

```
with resume_table as
(
    select 1 week, 10 total_new, 3 total_solved from dual union all
    select 2 week, 13 total_new, 15 total_solved from dual union all
    select 3 week, 6 total_new,  7 total_solved from dual
)
select week, prev_total, total_new, total_solved, new_total
from resume_table
model
    dimension by (week)
    measures (total_new, total_solved, 0 prev_total, 0 new_total)
    rules sequential order
    (
        new_total[any] order by week = 
            nvl(new_total[cv(week)-1], 0) + total_new[cv()] - total_solved[cv()]
        ,prev_total[any] order by week = nvl(new_total[cv(week)-1], 0)
    )
order by week;
```

Although this makes the assumption that WEEK is always a consecutive number.  If that's not true, you will want to add a `row_number()`.  Otherwise, the `-1` may not reference the previous value.

See this [SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/d41d8/2662).

Comment: This is fancy. I will take a look on it carefully. Thanks.

Comment: Hey, a few questions on your model. The week thing is not actually necessarily consecutive but I didn't really manage to add the `row_number()` as you mention without breaking it (sorry, I never used models before). Actually, I was not only trying to do that, but also add a few more dimensions to the data, which is causing me trouble in any way I try to do it. If you could give me a hand with this fiddle: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/aaedc/1 .. the outer `group by` is only to check the math, what I am really interested is the query within the `with` clause. thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Add one column in `RESUME_TABLE` (or create a view, which I think may be better):

```
RESUME_LEFT
WEEK | LEFT
1    | 7
2    | -2
3    | -1
```

Something like this:

```
CREATE VIEW resume_left
  (SELECT week,total_new-total_solved "left" FROM resume_table)
```

So in `REPORT_TABLE`, you can have an definition like this:

```
PREV_TOTAL=(SELECT sum(left) FROM RESUME_LEFT WHERE week<REPORT_TABLE.week)
```

---

**Edit**

OK, the view is unnecessary:

```
PREV_TOTAL=(SELECT sum(total_new)-sum(total_solved)
  FROM resume_table
  WHERE week<REPORT_TABLE.week)
```

Comment: Thanks, though it didn't really work. My actual "week" column is a date would that be a problem? also, I changed a bit the example (the numbers) to make it more clear.

Comment: @filippo It should work, because `sum(total_new)-sum(total_solved) where week<report.week` is actually the mathematical definition of your `prev_total`. And `date` type should not be a problem because it's comparable in Oracle and have the same ordering of your `week` in example (older means smaller value).

Comment: yeah, I see it makes sense though it only returns me empty columns. This is the actual code: http://pastebin.com/Cs9BLr5w (it is quite simple, and only changed the labels to match the question here). Mind taking a look?

Comment: @filippo Sorry that I don't have an accessible Oracle right now so I have to mind-debug actual code...Can you see if this work? http://pastebin.com/bnSQ5bHG

Comment: It does indeed. You Sir, just made my night worth it. Thanks a lot.